# ECMA 6 compatibility looks terrible. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm looking through the [compatibility list](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for JS6 and its not promising. According to that list it will be at least 3 years before it is usable for everyday use. Is this correct?

Comment: You can use it today, thanks to Babeljs.io

Comment: As said by @Jared, check Babeljs. Even reddit mobile site using it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the page you linked doesn't take into consideration browser market share.  For example, if there were a single browser with 100% coverage added to that page, the page as a whole would *still* look bad.  However, if that browser accounted for 95% of all browser market share, things would *actually* be pretty good.

The page also doesn't consider importance of features, only if it's supported or not.  While 100% compliance may be a long way off, vast amounts of useful features – like the spread operator – already have wide support.

In the meantime, as others have pointed out, there are many polyfill libraries available to help you bridge the gap until ECMAScript 6 is fully supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not JS6.  It is ES6, or ES2015.
2. IE has ceased development and will *always* be red.
3. Although red, most non-syntax features can be [shimmed](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), such as `Array.from`, `Promise`, and even `WeakMap`. Throw in a script and your code can use them.
4. In [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) you can directly use arrow functions, new object syntax, template string, array spread, promise, for of, const/let etc.
   They can simplify your code a lot.
5. Finally, we have [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which transforms your ES6 script to ES5 script.
     You can code ES6 now, run Babel, and get code that runs on any browsers.  There are [many ways](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) to run Babel, from [command line](http://blog.shinetech.com/2015/07/07/es6-with-babel-js/) to [in-browser](http://babeljs.io/repl/).

   Babel is the secret of the [javascript chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/57/javascript).
   We are using ES6 now and using it daily.

> A few language features simply cannot be done in ES5, in particular Proxy and subclassing, thus Babel do not support them.  [Firefox](http://mozilla.com.tw/firefox/new/) is the only browser to support Proxy, and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) supports an old syntax which can be [shimmed](https://github.com/Swatinem/proxy) into the final syntax.
>
> As you can guess, they can do things totally impossible before, and may change how you design your program; such a radical change does take years to mature and spread, regardless of language.